# How to Vertically and Horizontally Align Headers in Columns Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap:
I have 2 rows. first_row has 1 column. second_row has 2 columns. Each column has 1 header. The headers in each column are aligned at the top of the column and horizontally aligned in each's column, but I want each header vertically centered and horizontally centered in each column. How do I do this?

```
    <div class="row first_row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1>header1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row second_row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h2>header2</h2>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h2>header3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

.col-xs-12 {
height: 300px;
font-size: 100px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid black;
}
 h1 {
font-family: 'Seymour One', sans-serif;
font-size: 100px;
color: green;
}
.col-xs-6 {
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
border: 2px solid black;
text-align: center;
}
 h2 {
font-family: 'Seymour One', sans-serif;
font-size: 100px;
color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bad idea to add to what bootstap has for their grid classes its better to add your own. I wrapped your elements in a centering box and used that to align the headers. If you make the parent wrapper position relative and the child position absolute, you can then use top 50% to get it to move half the way down. However you then have to account for the hight of the element you are moving and adjust for it. In this case the header, which is font size 100, 0 margin and line-height 100. So we bring it back up 50px using margin-top:-50px

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/J3v9b/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row first_row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="centering-box">
                <h1>header1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row second_row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="centering-box">
                <h2>header2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="centering-box">
                <h2>header3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centering-box{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
.first_row .centering-box{
    height: 300px;
}
.second_row .centering-box {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
h1,h2{
    font-family: 'Seymour One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -50px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
h1 {
    color: green;
}
h2 {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Oh one problem: I added a column and now the columns have space between them (the middle column had a space on both right and left sides)

Comment: Also, how can I change the color of each column separately?

Comment: When I apply borders, it seems the centering box is more narrow than the columns (it doesn't fit the column perfectly).

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle showing what you are talking about?

Comment: I realized it is unnecessary to make a centering-box. I can label each column with a classname and header, like so: 
        <div class="col-xs-12 a_classname">
           <h1>header</h1>

and refer to the classname and header in the css, like so:

.a_classname {
     height: 100px;
     background-color: green;
}

h1 {
     position:absolute;
     top: 50%;
     text-align:center;
     line-height: 100px;
}

Thanks